# Symlinking or hardlinking (but not copying) files with Maven

Tags: maven, symlink

I'm switching an old web-application to using Maven rather than Ant. It goes mostly fine, but there is one thing I'm not sure about.

With customly written Ant build file I had a "development deployment mode", where it would *symlink* certain files (JSP and certain others) rather than copying them. This would result in a very streamlined development procedure: once you have deployment running, you just edit files in your source code checkout directory, and webserver picks up these changes automatically. Basically, you edit something in your editor, save file, and in a few seconds the changes automatically become visible through your browser, without any further steps.

How would I go about implementing something similar with Maven?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't seem possible without writing a custom plugin, I found `war:inplace` goal in `maven-war-plugin`, which achieves what I want.  The only downside is that I have to keep JSP files, JS files, images etc. together in `src/main/webapp` rather than have them logically separated in e.g. `src/main/jsp`, `src/main/js`, but that's not that important.